# CSP with GTM loading api with external connection

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I'm trying to configure my CSP to allow GTM to load script with external connection like clarity.

I can make it work by adding clarity url to the `connect-src` directive.
Is there a way to make it automatic like the `strict-dynamic` for the `script-src` ?

my csp for référence:

```
content="default-src 'self';
    connect-src 'self' https://*.clarity.ms https://c.bing.com;
    img-src * data: www.googletagmanager.com;
    script-src 'unsafe-inline' https: 'nonce-{{nonce}}' 'strict-dynamic'"
```